# How do I use `ifpackageloaded` inside a `cls` file?

Tags: packages, conditionals, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I am writing a class that makes some changes in its commands according to the packages that are loaded in the main `tex` file. However, when is use `\@ifpackageloaded` for that purpose, it only performs the changes when the package is loaded in the very `cls` file instead of in the `tex` file.
However, I need it to work loading the packages in the `tex` file.

For a minimal example, let us have the `cls` file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myarticle}[3000/13/32 myarticle LaTeX class]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{article}

%\usepackage{descartes}

\newcommand{\myquote}{Wovon man nicht sprechen kann...}

\@ifpackageloaded{descartes}%
    {\renewcommand{\myquote}{Cogito ergo sum.}}{}
```

And the following `tex` file:

```
\documentclass{myarticle}

%\usepackage{descartes}

\begin{document}

\myquote

\end{document}
```

LaTeX only prints the string "Cogito ergo sum." when I uncomment `\usepackage{descartes}` in the `cls` file, but it has no effect if I only uncomment it in the `tex` file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your test is before the package loading, so naturally it gives false. You will have to delay the execution, e.g. with \AtBeginDocument.

Comment: Alternatively, if you actually conditionally use commands defined in a package (which you don't do in this example but I suspect you do in your actual use case), then you can test if such a commnd is defined. Something like `\myquote{\@ifundefined{\descartescommand}{Wovon man ...}{Cogito ...}}`. Not fully fail-safe (the command could be defined by other packages or by the user) but possibly useful in practise.

Comment: @Marijn `descartescommand` not `\descartescommand` ?

Comment: @cfr you're right, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @UlrikeFischerad, but the code that I need to execute (in the condition that the packages are loaded) is way bigger than that (and there's more than one `ifpackageloaded` command). I'm not sure if it is a good idea to hook that much code before the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative solution**

As you are not sure that delaying to `\AtBeginDocument` is a good or bad idea, I suggest to use a `descartes` option which loads the package and modifies the sentence.

Here is the code of the `.cls` file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2019/10/22 A test class to answer on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange.]

\newif\ifdescartes
\descartesfalse
\DeclareOption{descartes}{\descartestrue}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{article}


\newcommand{\myquote}{Wovon man nicht sprechen kann...}

\ifdescartes
    \RequirePackage{descartes}

    \renewcommand{\myquote}{Cogito ergo sum.}
\fi
```

Here is the code of the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{testclass}% without `descartes` option
%\documentclass[descartes]{testclass}% with `descartes` option

\begin{document}

    \myquote

\end{document}
```